# Link shared library with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I have the following project structure:

[image]

- `libs` is the directory where the standalone library I'm writing lives.
- `src` is where I consume the library

My three `CMakeLists.txt` files are the following:

The main entry point:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
    add_subdirectory(src)
    add_subdirectory(libs)
```

The `libs/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Fibula)

message(STATUS "Fibula: v2.0.0")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -framework OpenGl -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lGLEW -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic")

set(FIBULA_INCLUDE_DIR "include")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

include_directories(${FIBULA_INCLUDE_DIR})

# This stuff needed to put every include file into needed directory when we do make install
file(GLOB BRIDGE ${FIBULA_INCLUDE_DIR}/Bridge/*.hpp)
file(GLOB CORE ${FIBULA_INCLUDE_DIR}/Core/*.hpp)
file(GLOB EVENTS ${FIBULA_INCLUDE_DIR}/Events/*.hpp)
file(GLOB GRAPHICS ${FIBULA_INCLUDE_DIR}/Graphics/*.hpp)
file(GLOB GRAPHICS_TILEMAP ${FIBULA_INCLUDE_DIR}/Graphics/TileMap/*.hpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_LIST src/*.cpp)

set(HEADER_LIST
    ${BRIDGE}
    ${CORE}
    ${EVENTS}
    ${GRAPHICS}
    ${GRAPHICS_TILEMAP}
    )

# GLM
find_package(GLM REQUIRED)
if (NOT GLM_FOUND)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Failed to find GLM")
    return()
else ()
    include_directories(${GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif ()

# GLEW
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
if (NOT GLEW_FOUND)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Failed to find GLEW")
    return()
else ()
    include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif ()

# SFML
find_package(SFML 2.2 REQUIRED)
if (NOT SFML_FOUND)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Failed to find SFML 2")
    return()
else ()
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif ()

add_library(Fibula SHARED ${SOURCE_LIST} ${HEADER_LIST})

target_link_libraries(Fibula
                      ${GLM_LIBRARIES}
                      ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
                      ${SFML_LIBARIES}
                      )

# When we do 'make install' it will put .so file into lib directory and include files into include directory
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} LIBRARY DESTINATION ${PROJECT_NAME})
install(FILES ${BRIDGE} DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}/Bridge/)
install(FILES ${CORE} DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}/Core/)
install(FILES ${EVENTS} DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}/Events/)
install(FILES ${GRAPHICS} DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}/Graphics/)
install(FILES ${GRAPHICS_TILEMAP} DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}/Graphics/TileMap/)

add_custom_target(install_${PROJECT_NAME}
                  make install
                  DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME}
                  COMMENT "Installing ${PROJECT_NAME}")
```

And the `src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(demo-game)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -Wall")

find_library(FIBULA_LIBRARY
             NAMES Fibula
             HINTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../libs/include/")

include_directories(
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../libs/include"
        Core
)

file(GLOB SOURCE_LIST
     *.cpp
     ../../src/Core/*.cpp
     )

add_executable(demo-game ${SOURCE_LIST})
target_link_libraries(demo-game Fibula)

add_custom_target(valgrind)
```

When I try to include my library as:

```
#include <Fibula/Core/Kernel.hpp>
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: This is not about linking. Maybe not yet. Is `Fibula` an actual directory?

Comment: I think it could be about compiling. How should I compile the library?

Comment: Is `Fibula` a folder that its parent folder was added to your `include_directories`?

Comment: No. Fibula doesn't exist as a folder, only as a namespace.

Comment: Fibula is not a directory, only a namespace. Do I need to create this directory? If not, how do I specify that the include starts from include/?

Comment: `#include <Fibula/Core/Kernel.hpp>` requires `Fibula` to be a folder that has its parent folder listed as of one of your folders that is in one of your `include_directories()` statements in your `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: What if I want to reference as <Fibula/...> and **not** have the folder?

Comment: You will have to change your include statements then to not require the path structure.

Comment: But how do I do it?

Comment: Edit the `c++` code with the include statements. Possibly using a search and replace function of your ide.